# How to set 404 pages whith a status code 404 instead of 200 in Spartacus

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

My understanding is that you can customize the *404 Component* by setting:

`{ path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent }`

However, it returns the HTTP status code 200.

How can I return status code 404?

Answer (score 0):

By doing this, you are creating a path for `/404` which means it is valid returning 200. You should be attempting to navigate to a url you have not configured any path for to be returned a 404 status code.

You need to configure your 404 page from backoffice by searching for a page with label or id as "not-found" or similar. You can check with the url in your network traffic:
[image]